# How to identify number of occurrences before specific even

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a data set of repeat customers who purchase one product at a time and would like to know how many times they purchased until they bought a specific item. I have customer id, timestamp of visit, and purchase made.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correcty, you can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select customer_id, product_ts, count(*) as num_products_before
from (select t.*,
             min(case when product = :product then timestamp end) over (partition by customerid) as product_ts
      from t
     ) t
where timestamp < product_ts
group by customer_id, product_ts;
```